# How to generate random value in python list without re-running the code

Tags: python, list

so i have these following items within a list

```
greeting_res = random.choice(['Hey There!', 'Hola!', 'Sup!', 'Oi!', 'Wassupp!', 'Hello!'])
```

and I want to get a different value everytime I input the word 'hey'

```
while True:
    userinput = input('You: ')
    if userinput == 'hey':
        print(greeting_res)
```

it actually does give me a random item at the first place, but when I try to do it for the next time I get the same value

Comment: In the first piece of code you set `greeting_res` to be the result of `random.choice`. In the second piece of code you're only calling that result. You're not calling `random.choice` again. To call it again, look at the answer provided by @mcsoini

Comment: You are assigning one random choice to the variable `greeting_res`, instead put the `random.choice` in the while block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a new random choice every time, you need to generate one each time, i.e. after each input:

```
greeting_options = ['Hey There!', 'Hola!', 'Sup!', 'Oi!', 'Wassupp!', 'Hello!']

while True:
    userinput = input('You: ')
    if userinput == 'hey':
        print(random.choice(greeting_options))
```

Comment: how the heck i did not think of that, thanks for your help!

Comment: sure, your answer helps me a lot!

Comment: maybe i have to wait for 4 minutes, that's what it says when I click the check button